# Querying SQL table from C# dropdown list

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ssms

I have a drop down list on one form that populates a puzzle id code from a sql table. 
when the user selects a puzzle code say "puzzle2" i want the next form(play:Form) to display this puzzle. At the moment i can only get it to display the 1st puzzle "puzzle1" on the page.

The database consists of puzzleID which is the puzzle type and puzzle which is the  puzzle question itself.

```
public partial class Play : Form

{

    public Play()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAURA-PC;Initial Catalog=Sudoku;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select puzzle from Puzzle";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string[] tokens = ((string)reader[0]).Split(';');

            textBox1.Text = tokens[0];
            textBox2.Text = tokens[1];
            textBox3.Text = tokens[2];
            textBox4.Text = tokens[3];
            textBox5.Text = tokens[4];
            textBox6.Text = tokens[5];
            textBox7.Text = tokens[6];
            textBox8.Text = tokens[7];
            textBox9.Text = tokens[8];
            textBox10.Text = tokens[9];
            textBox11.Text = tokens[10];
            textBox12.Text = tokens[11];
            textBox13.Text = tokens[12];
            textBox14.Text = tokens[13];
            textBox15.Text = tokens[14];
            textBox16.Text = tokens[15];
        }
        conn.Close();

    }
```

I know i need to implement some sort of of global variable from the drop down list in the previous form and then try filter that variable into Where statement? But im having no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an static class as a common place to share objects. All classes can see this class and use its members.

```
public static class CommonClass
{
   public static String puzzleCode ;
}
```

Also you can have a property on the second form to accept the puzzle id. Like this :

```
public class SecondForm : Form
{
   private String _puzzleId ;

   public String PuzzleId
   {
      get { return _puzzleId ; }
      set { _puzzleId = value ; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Passing variable to form.**

```
Play frmPlay = new Play(puzzleId);
frmPlay.Show();

your Play class will be changed by this

public Play(int puzzleId)
{ 
 //Unchanged code
 command.CommandText = "Select puzzle from Puzzle where puzzleId = "+puzzleId;

 //Unchanged code
}
```

**2. Passing data through delegate**

**Add a delegate signature to form1 as below:**

```
public delegate void delPassData(int puzzleId);

Play frmPlay= new Play ();
delPassData del=new delPassData(frmPlay.SetPuzzleId);
del( Convert.ToInt32(cmBxPuzzleId.SelectedValue));
frmPlay.Show();

**In Play form write this code**

private int m_PuzzleId;
public void SetPuzzleId(int puzzleId )
{
    m_PuzzleId = puzzuleId; 
}
```